# Turn String of object back into object Kotlin

Tags: android, string, object

I have an object that I wrote to a file and now I want to take that string I get from the file to turn it back into an object for me to use.

Object class:

```
@Serializable
class DrinkItem {
    
    @SerializedName("strAlcoholic")
    val alcoholic: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient1")
    val ingredient1: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient10")
    val ingredient10: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient11")
    val ingredient11: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient12")
    val ingredient12: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient13")
    val ingredient13: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient14")
    val ingredient14: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient15")
    val ingredient15: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient2")
    val ingredient2: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient3")
    val ingredient3: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient4")
    val ingredient4: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient5")
    val ingredient5: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient6")
    val ingredient6: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient7")
    val ingredient7: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient8")
    val ingredient8: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient9")
    val ingredient9: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strInstructions")
    val instructions: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure1")
    val measurement1: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure10")
    val measurement10: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure11")
    val measurement11: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure12")
    val measurement12: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure13")
    val measurement13: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure14")
    val measurement14: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure15")
    val measurement15: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure2")
    val measurement2: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure3")
    val measurement3: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure4")
    val measurement4: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure5")
    val measurement5: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure6")
    val measurement6: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure7")
    val measurement7: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure8")
    val measurement8: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure9")
    val measurement9: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strDrink")
    val name: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strDrinkThumb")
    val thumbnail: String? = null
}
```

I use this function to write the object to a file:

```
    private fun writeToFile(fileName: String, byteArray: ByteArray){

        val lineSeparator: String = System.getProperty("line.separator") as String

        // File
        val path = context!!.filesDir
        val directory = File(path, "LET")
        directory.mkdirs()
        val file = File(directory, fileName)

        //append drink to file
        FileOutputStream(file, true).use {
            it.write(byteArray)
            it.write(lineSeparator.toByteArray())
        }
    }
```

After the function is done with the object it is turned into this string:

```
{"alcoholic":"Alcoholic","ingredient1":"Apricot brandy","ingredient2":"Triple sec","ingredient3":"Lime","ingredient4":"Lime","instructions":"Shake all ingredients (except lime wedge) with ice and strain into a cocktail glass. Add the wedge of lime and serve.","measurement1":"1 oz ","measurement2":"1 oz ","measurement3":"Juice of 1 ","measurement4":"1 ","name":"After Dinner Cocktail","thumbnail":"https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/vtytxq1483387578.jpg"}
```

Is there a function or library that would help me turn a string of an object into said object?

Comment: What is the format of your String Object? JSON?

Comment: Can you paste your code in question? It's essential to know how you wrote the file

Comment: @Enowneb Does this help any?

Comment: @TYZRPVX Does this help any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using library to convert your `DrinkItem` to the outputting JSON String? Seems that the keys in your JSON String do not match with what you have named in `@SerializedName()`.

You can use the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to handle JSON String and Object conversion.

For example, if you have the same `DrinkItem` class, you can convert your `DrinkItem` into JSON String as following:

```kotlin
// Define DrinkItem and set some of the attributes
val drinkItemTest = DrinkItem()
drinkItemTest.alcoholic = "Alcohol One"
drinkItemTest.ingredient1 = "Ingredient One"
// Use Gson library to convert Object to JSON String
val drinkItemTestString = Gson().toJson(drinkItemTest)
println(drinkItemTestString)
```

**Output**

> {"strAlcoholic":"Alcohol One","strIngredient1":"Ingredient One"}

And to convert your JSON String back to `DrinkItem`, you can do something like this:

```kotlin
// Read the whole JSON String from your file here
val drinkItemString = "{\"strAlcoholic\":\"Alcohol One\",\"strIngredient1\":\"Ingredient One\"}"
// And make use of Gson library to convert your JSON String into DrinkItem Object
val drinkItem = Gson().fromJson(drinkItemString, DrinkItem::class.java)
```

Comment: Gson solved all my problems, thank you!